# while loop not working with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

On [this page](http://buildworx-mc.com/#recent-screenshots) I am trying to limit the amount of images shown. I tried the following but it keeps crashing tab.

```
while (screenshots.length < 5) {
    $.each(images, function (i, el) {
                    startHTML += "<a href=\"" + link + "\" title=\"" + title + "\">";
                    startHTML += "<img src=\"" + el + "\" alt=\"\" width=\"200px\" height=\"200px\">";
                    startHTML += "</a>";
                });
}
```

The images are getting pulled in from json.. full code:

```
var screenshots = $('#recent-screenshots span');



       // get screenshots we can pass limit here if we want
        $.getJSON("gallery/getScreenshots.php", function (data) {
            var startHTML = "";
            $.each(data, function (i, image) {
                var link = image.link;
                var title = image.title;
                var images = image.images;

                $.each(images, function (i, el) {
                    startHTML += "<a href=\"" + link + "\" title=\"" + title + "\">";
                    startHTML += "<img src=\"" + el + "\" alt=\"\" width=\"200px\" height=\"200px\">";
                    startHTML += "</a>";
                });


            });
            screenshots.html(startHTML);

        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your while loop never terminates

Comment: What is `data` anyway? Can you please post its contents?

Comment: data is the json result, which is link=http://site.com title=threadtitle and images=imageurl

Comment: @nowayyy: OK so there are many images that have a single link and you want to show 5 images for each link. (That was confusing me a bit at first.)

Comment: No, just 5 images in the div it's being appended too.

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop:

```
while (screenshots.length < 5) {
    $.each(images, function (i, el) {
                    startHTML += "<a href=\"" + link + "\" title=\"" + title + "\">";
                    startHTML += "<img src=\"" + el + "\" alt=\"\" width=\"200px\" height=\"200px\">";
                    startHTML += "</a>";
                });
}
```

Your condition for the while loop involves screenshots.length, but you never modify that value inside the while loop so if the condition is initially true, it stays true forever in the while loop.

You can fix it by iterating manually through the images and just doing the smaller of the length or 5.

```
for (var i = 0, len = Math.min(images.length, 5); i < len; i++) {
    startHTML += "<a href=\"" + link + "\" title=\"" + title + "\">";
    startHTML += "<img src=\"" + images[i] + "\" alt=\"\" width=\"200px\" height=\"200px\">";
    startHTML += "</a>";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not decrementing/incrementing the variable thatcontrols the loop i think. You could try something like

```
var maxNumber = screenshots.length, c = 0;
while (c  < maxNumber) {
    $.each(images, function (i, el) {
                    startHTML += "<a href=\"" + link + "\" title=\"" + title + "\">";
                    startHTML += "<img src=\"" + el + "\" alt=\"\" width=\"200px\" height=\"200px\">";
                    startHTML += "</a>";
                });
      c++;
}
```